# Command line input and output in visual studio 19

Tags: c++, c, file, csv

I have written a program which takes 2 csv files as command line argument. It takes data from one csv and writes its output to other csv file. The program runs correctly when command arguments are given through visual studio project property page -> Configuration properties ->Debugging -> Command Arguments. But I want to give the command arguments through cmd i.e by running the .exe file. What should i do?

[image]

Comment: Open command prompt, navigate to where the exe is located. Use it as you would any other command line program?

Comment: Should work like any other console application that takes parameters, did you try it? If yes, what failed?

Comment: The same arguments you typed in the picture you type after the program name in your `cmd.exe` instance. However you need your application to be in the path. The simplest way is change directory to the location of your .exe file. You could also adjust your windows `PATH` environment variable to add the location of your executable then typing from a cmd.exe will find your executable (provided there is not another executable with the same name already in the PATH)

Comment: ***What should i do?*** You probably need a tutorial on how to properly use `cmd.exe`. [https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/windows-command-prompt-introduction/](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/windows-command-prompt-introduction/)

Comment: _**What should i do?**_ [Edit] the question and show us the relevant parts of your code (the part that open the files). And possibly improve your error handling.

Comment: I believe the question is not about the code instead its about how to use the command line in windows. Or perhaps the OP thought that in the file explorer you could type the arguments.

Comment: Thank you all, I figured it out from reading the links.

Answer (score 0):

using windows, if your program executable's name is 'addItems' then:

> `addItems <infile >outfile`